# Web-scraping macro only working when I add a msgbox

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a web-scraping macro using Google Translate. I wrote a very simple prototype just to help me understand the key elements. But for some reason its only working if I add a msgbox to the code (Msgbox "fefe"). If I take it out the ecoll object is not saved and I can't "call" it in the loop. Any ideas why?

```
Sub Translate1212()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim ecoll As Object
Dim lang1 As String
Dim lang2 As String
Dim inputtext As String
Dim outputtext As String

lang1 = "auto"
lang2 = "fr"
inputtext = "What is your name"

ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "https://translate.google.com/#" & lang1 & "/" & _
lang2 & "/" & inputtext

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = ie.Document

MsgBox "fefe"



Set ecoll = doc.getElementsByClassName("tlid-translation translation")

For Each element In ecoll
    outputtext = element.innerText
    Range("G5").Value = outputtext

Next element

End Sub
```

Comment: I ran your code with the msgbox line commented out and it still worked for me. Furthermore, I can't think of any reason a messagebox would be key to making this work. Likely, it something to do with pausing execution for a moment

Comment: @ArcherBird Yeah, it really doesn't make sense to me either. I'd like to do it without adding a wait, as ideally I'd be translating large batches of text.

Comment: One other thing to be aware of in your code (unrelated to your question) is that you are leaving open an instance of Internet Explorer hidden in the background processes whenever you run this code. You might want to add something to clean that up

Comment: You can't loop over translating several texts without a short break. The translator needs time to translate, because it's not possible to translate more than one text at time. Excel works not parallel. If you need a break under 1 second, use `sleep()`